# Set state for a button in a ListView

Tags: flutter, listview

I have an input page to create a new reminder. On this page you will select several different variables (reminder type, start date, etc.) - at this stage I am just trying to get it work for two variables.

I have a button object that I create, which takes some text, a "isSelected" value (which changes the color to show it is selected) and an onPress callback. The plan is to use a loop to create one of these buttons for each of the necessary selection options and then feed that into a ListView, so you have a scroll-able list of selection option. As you select the item the properties of the new reminder object will update and the color will change to selected.

When I click the button, the value is selected (the print statement shows this) but the button does not change to the new isSelected value, despite a SetState being used. What is it I am missing here? Is it possible to feed buttons into a ListView like this and still have their state update? Or do you need to find another work around?

```
class AddReminder extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddReminderState createState() => _AddReminderState();
}

class _AddReminderState extends State<AddReminder> {
  String addReminder = "";

  Reminder newReminder = Reminder();

  @override
  List<Widget> getReminderTypesButton(
      String selectionName, List selectionOptions, var reminderVariable) {
    // create new list to add widgets to
    List<Widget> selectionOptionsWidgets = [];

    // loop through selection options and create buttons
    for (String selection in selectionOptions) {
      bool isSelectedValue = false;
      selectionOptionsWidgets.add(
        FullWidthButton(
          text: selection,
          isSelected: isSelectedValue,
          onPress: () {
            setState(() {
              reminderVariable = selection;
              isSelectedValue = true;
            });
            print(reminderVariable);
          },
        ),
      );
    }
    ;

    // return list of widgets
    return selectionOptionsWidgets;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<List<Widget>> newList = [
      getReminderTypesButton("Type", reminderTypesList, newReminder.type),
      getReminderTypesButton(
          "Frequency", repeatFrequencyTypesList, newReminder.repeatFrequency)
    ];

    List<Widget> widgetListUnwrap(List<List<Widget>> inputList) {
      //takes list of list of widgets and converts to widget list (to feed into list view)
      List<Widget> widgetsUnwrapped = [];
      for (var mainList in inputList) {
        for (var widgets in mainList) {
          widgetsUnwrapped.add(widgets);
        }
      }
      return widgetsUnwrapped;
    }

    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Hero(
                tag: addReminder,
                child: TopBarWithBack(
                  mainText: "New reminder",
                  onPress: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                )),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView(
                  children: widgetListUnwrap(newList),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the lists that I reference

```
List<String> reminderTypesList = [
  "Appointment",
  "Check-up",
  "Other",
];

List<String> repeatFrequencyTypesList = [
  "Never",
  "Daily",
  "Weekly",
  "Monthly",
  "Every 3 months",
  "Every 6 months",
  "Yearly",
];

List<List<String>> selectionOptions = [
  reminderTypesList,
  repeatFrequencyTypesList
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your state not changing is that every time you call `setState()`, the whole `build` function will run again. If you initiate a state (in this case `isSelectedValue`) within the `build` method (since the `getReminderTypesButton()` got called within the `build`), the code will run through the below line again and again, resetting the state to the initial value.

```
bool isSelectedValue = false;
```

This line will always set the `isSelectedValue` to `false`, no matter how many time you call `setState`.

In order to avoid this, you need to place the state outside of the `build` method, ideally in the `FullWidthButton` like this:

```
class FullWidthButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const FullWidthButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FullWidthButtonState createState() => _FullWidthButtonState();
}

class _FullWidthButtonState extends State<FullWidthButton> {
  
  bool isSelectedValue = false;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => setState(() => isSelectedValue = !isSelectedValue),
      // ...other lines
    );
  }
}
```